# Find the total number of solutions of $ \log_e |\sin x| = - x^2 + 2x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find   the total number of solutions of $ \log_e |\sin x| = - x^2 + 2x $  in 0 to $ \pi $ close interval.

So my book solves this problem by making graph. I am a high school student. I don't know how to make graph of such functions. 
I know the graph of log and I I know the graph of |sin| but I don't know how to solve this sin inside log.

If you can give a source which teaches that , that will solve my problem. I am not allowed to use calculator.

I tried solving the equations, I also tied finding range  of both the sides to see if there is any intersection.

Comment: You _should_ know how to draw (or at least sketch) these graphs. The right side is completely standard. For the left, you know what the graph of $\sin x$ looks like, and you should know what applying absolute value does to a graph. From there it takes a little bit of thinking (but not much) to see what applying the logarithm does to the graph. Keep in mind important points (like where the different intermediate graphs are $0$ and $1$), and you should be fine.

Comment: @Arthur. Yes, the log part is the problem!! I know log x and I know | sin x| but  one inside other is the problem!

Comment: I always find, if in doubt, sticking a few known $x$-values into the equation to see what it does can help quickly sketch something. Hope this helps you sketch it out :)
For example, multiples of $\pi/4$ to see what happens (hopefully you will realise that the function is undefined for integer multiples of $\pi$)

Comment: @stevengregory I did mention that I am not allowed to use any find of calculator. : )

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see the difference between the graphs of $|\sin(x)|$ and $\log|\sin(x)|$. Below, you can see what the log function does to the $|\sin(x)|$. 
[image]

Now, let's talk about the computational side. I assume you may use a calculator. For graphing such functions, constructing a table would be a wise option. To obtain a value for each step, if you are unfamiliar, you can do the following. Assume you want to calculate the $y$ value for $x=\pi/2 \ (\approx 1.57)$ (you can also enter the following in one line in your calculator).

`sin(pi/2)
  1
log(ans)
  0`

which is in line with the graph above. Now compute several of these points to graph the function yourself.

I assume you are now ready to start building your own table, and thereby also graphing your function? If not, or you want to check, I will provide a small table below.

Exercise for you: explain the symmetry within the table, and why did I choose my $x$ this way?

[image]